# Determine if the following family, $\mathcal{F}$, of continuous functions is compact: $\{x^{n}\} \cup \{0\}$ in $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, arzela-ascoli

Determine if the following family, $\mathcal{F}$, of continuous functions is compact: $\{x^{n}\} \cup \{0\}$ in $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$

To do this I have to appeal to the Arzela Ascoli Theorem. In particular I have to establish that this family, $\mathcal{F}$, is:

- Bounded
- Closed
- Equicontinous

At the moment I am having trouble establishing if this family is closed or not. But I think it has more to do with how I'm using the idea of showing a set is closed in general.

So to show that this family $\mathcal{F}$ is closed I have to show that all of this sets limit points are in the set.

Observe that $f_{n}(x) = x^{n} \to 0$, when $n \to \infty$, when $x \in [0,\frac{1}{2}]$.

**Proof:** Suppose $f_{n}(x)$ converges uniformly to $f(x) \in C([0,\frac{1}{2}])$, where $f_{n} \in \mathcal{F}$.

*Want to show:* $f(x) = 0 \in \mathcal{F}$

This is where I'm stuck and feel I probably shouldn't be since I've done questions like this before involving real numbers.

I have to somehow show that $\|f_{n}(x) - f(x)\|_{\infty} \to 0$.  I think....maybe I'm not even supposed to use the uniform norm in this scenario. As can be seen I'm stuck. SUggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: I might be missing something but you stated that the family is $\mathcal{F} = \{x_n\} \cup \{0\}$ so the function $f(x) = 0$ is already in $\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: You seem to be overcomplicating the last part. Notice that $f_n$ can be proved to converge uniformly to the zero function directly. In this case, uniqueness of the limit implies your general limit point $f$ should be the zero function.

Comment: So simply by showing that the convergence is uniform that is enough to show $f(x) = 0 \in \mathcal{F}$?....I feel there must be something more, because I'm assuming that $f_{n}(x)$ is already converging uniformly to $f(x)$.

Comment: Maybe there is some confusion on what your $f_n$ means. If $f_n = x^n$, then it converges to the zero function. If you are considering a general sequence $f_n \in \mathcal{F}$ ,  your claim is not true, it could be a sequence $f_n = x^2$ for every $n$

Comment: The reasoning should be something like suppose $f_n$ converges to $f$ if $f_n$ contains infinitely many different $x^j$, then we have a subsequence converging to zero and the whole sequence converges also. Otherwise, $f_n$ only assumes a finite number of possible functions, and the limit must be one of them.

Comment: Yes it is $f_{n}(x) = x^{n}$, that converges to the zero function.

Comment: @Daniel, How would I show it converges to the zero function directly? $\|x^{n} - 0\| = \|x^{n}\| < \epsilon$ $\Rightarrow n \ln(x) < \epsilon$.....then what?

Comment: It is a discret set that converge to zero. It is enough, is not?

Comment: @dc3rd To show directly, just notice that $||f_n|| \le 2^{-n}$ uniformly on $[0, 1/2]$.

Comment: I really have to remember that $2^{-n}$ is different to $\lim_{n \to \infty} 2^{-n}$. So $2^{-n}$ would be larger than anything in my set. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Alternative proof: In any topological space $\{x,x_1,x_2,...\}$ is compact if $x_n \to x$. This is because any open cover has a member containing $x$ and this member contains all but finitely many of the $x_n$'s. Hence there is a finite subcover. In the present case $|x^{n}| \leq (\frac 1 2)^{n} $ so $x^{n} \to 0$ uniformly.

Thus Arzela - Ascoli Theorem is an overkill for this question.

Comment: I brought up Arzela Ascoli mainly because there is a first part to the question which asks about equicontinuity. Also since I'm dealing with function space.